# Optimization of a staircase surface

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, machine-learning

I am trying to find the minimum of some unexplored "staircase like" surface - image many Rastrigin functions side by side (some with a higher center and some with a lower center) but with flat parts instead of smooth bumps. The slope at any point is either undefined or $0$.

The best solutions I have found so far are "pattern search" and "genetic algorithms". I was also thinking that "coordinate descent" with "simulated annealing" might work as well.

Does anyone have suggestions or thoughts?

Comment: Do you have an explicit formulation of the function you wish to optimize?

Comment: There is no explicit formulation. This surface is calculated empirically from a dataset.